# One of my Ai CS6 file suddenly won't open anymore

Tags: adobe-illustrator, file-corruption, open, illustrator-cs6

So I have about 20-30 illustrator files in a folder (mainly mock-ups for a website), all in .ai format, working on CS6.
This morning I tried opening the last one I was working on but it display the following error message : "There was an error opening this document. The root object is missing or invalid."
I tried to change the file extension to eps, svg, pdf but everytime I get the same error. The file still weights 11 Mo so I guess my content is still there somewhere.
This represent several working days, I can't just lose this file...
 
Thanks for your help

Comment: Just restore it from your backup.

Comment: I wouldn't ask this if I had a backup

Comment: You can try to open the file in Inkscape [link](https://inkscape.org/en/) and save as SVG